# Why does wget not get all the pages when mirroring this site

Tags: wget, mirroring

I want to mirror the following web site completely: http://tinaztitiz.com

I use the following wget command:

```
wget -m http://tinaztitiz.com
```

The web site is a custom CMS and contains lots of pages having the following form of urls:

```
http://tinaztitiz.com/yazi.php?id=943
http://tinaztitiz.com/yazi.php?id=762
```

Oddly, wget gets a few of these pages but not all of them. I wonder what might be the reason for this?

Note: There is no constraining due to robots.txt.

**Update:**

Looking at the source code of the web site, I noticed that the pages that are not detected and crawled by wget have a common property. Their anchor urls are written by the following javascript function:

```
function yazilar()
{
var ab = '</a><br class=\"hide\" />';
var aa = '<a class=' + '\"nav sub\" href=\"kategori.php?id=';
var ac = '';

var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = '12\">'+ac+' Belâgat';
arr[1] = '15\">'+ac+' Bilim ve Teknoloji';
//...
maxi = 14;
for(i=0;i<maxi;i++) {
    a = aa + arr[i] + ab;
    document.writeln(a);
    }
}
```

So, it looks like wget cannot detect anchor tags that are generated dynamically.

Comment: In other words, you need wget to execute Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is rendered by the browser. `wget` does exactly what it's supposed to do, fetching the content. Browsers do the same thing initially. They get the content exactly how you posted above. But then it renders the `Javascript` part and builds the links. `wget` can't do that. So, no, you can't get links that are generated dynamically, using just wget. You can try something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) though.

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, wget is not able to generate pages that use client-side JavaScript code. If you know the basics of Python programming, I would recommend using the Python library [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) for crawling the web site, together with [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which is able to use an external browser to generate dynamic pages. You can do all this with a tiny amount of Python code. See for example
[Code Snippets Collection](http://icodesnip.com/search/javascript%20scrapy/).